# Ext.select("div.x-grid-panel").elements[0].id is not working for mozilla browser

Tags: extjs

I have found the mentioned code["Ext.select("div.x-grid-panel").elements[0].id"] here in this site,this is working well for IE only,for other browsers it is not working. It is failing to get Grid`s id...I`m working on Ext-JS 3...any help would be great..Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get on console by logging `console.log(Ext.select('.x-grid-panel'))` ? post code of your grid ...

Answer (score 0):

first you need to register your grid. You can register your grid through Ext.reg('',) Like below,

```
Ext.ns("Ext.xyz.abc");

Ext.xyz.abc.CreditCardReportGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {


    constructor : function(store) {
        Ext.apply(this,{
            id : 'creditCardReportGridId',
            name : 'creditCardReportGridId',
            store : store,
            columns : [
            {header : 'Report Type', width : 247,dataIndex:'reportType'},
            {header : 'Brand', width : 247,dataIndex:'brand'},
            {header : 'Processing Date', width : 247,dataIndex:'processingDate'},
            {header : 'Amount', width : 78,dataIndex:'amount', renderer : 'usMoney'}
            ],

            stripeRows: true,
            autoHeight: true,           
            autoWidth: true,
            loadMask: true,

            bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                        pageSize: Ext.APPLICATION_PAGE_SIZE,
                        store: store,
                        displayInfo: true,
                        displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
                        emptyMsg: 'No Records'
            })
        });

        Ext.xyz.abc.CreditCardReportGrid.superclass.constructor.apply(this,arguments);
    }
});

Ext.reg('creditCardReportGrid',Ext.xyz.abc.CreditCardReportGrid);
```

After registering your grid, you can get your grid through Ext.getCmp() from any your js file. For Example,

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('creditCardReportGrid');
```

Once you get your whole grid, you will get grid's id also.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,but the problem is here we have to mention our grid id.I don`t want to mention grid`s id,I thought of using div.x-grid-panel for other browsers also..isn`t it possible???"Ext.getCmp(Ext.select("div.x-grid-panel").elements[0].id).getStore().reload()" is working well for me but only in IE

Comment: In extjs, you are not defining any div tag. You just define Grid through ExtJs and in back-end js will create div according to you designed your grid. So, whenever you want to access your grid, you need to define id and you can access through only Ext.getCmp().